# Showing the solution of a recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I've been working through recurrence relation problems and came across one that I am struggling with

Say we have a relation as follows

$r_k - 7r_{k-1} + 12r_{k-2} = 0$ for all $k \geq 2$ and $r_0 = 1, r_1 = 7$

The problem is essentially asking whether for any $a_n$, does $a_n = n3^n+4^n$

Now the base cases hold, but I'm unsure of how to proceed for proving for all $n$

Comment: $r_n=4^{n+1}-3^{n+1}$

Comment: Chu  you typed in $a_n = n 3^n + 4^n.$ In some circumstances, this is allowed, but not here. As J.W. says, it must be a constant times $3^n$ plus another constant times $4^n$

Comment: Okay so it isn't true for any an, but as I am learning about this it would be cool to have an explanation why

Comment: Why not just compute $a_2$ and $r_2$ and see if those match?

Comment: Right I see so by computing r2 we get 6 (7 - 1) and then by computing a2 we get 32 (18 + 16) so we have a contradiction? Did I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recurrence relations of the form
$$a_n= A_1 \cdot a_{n-1} + A_2 \cdot a_{n-2}$$
Have the general solution
$$a_n = c_0 {r_0}^n + c_1 {r_1}^n$$
Where $r_0$ and $r_1$ are solutions of the **characteristic equation**
$$t^2 - A_1t - A_2 =0$$
And $c_0, c_1$ satisfy the simultaneous equations
$$a_0= c_0 {r_0}^0 + c_1 {r_1}^0 = c_0+c_1$$
And
$$a_1 = c_0 {r_0}^1 + c_1 {r_1}^1 = c_0 r_0 + c_1 r_1$$
It's easy to see how this generalizes to higher order linear homogeneous difference equations as well.

Use $A_1=7$ and $A_2=-12$ to solve your problem. Wolfram Alpha gives
$$r_n = 4^{n+1} - 3^{n+1}.$$

Comment: Unless $r_0=r_1=r$, in which case you have $a_n=(c_0n+c_1)r^n$.